# Can C++ std::vector handle push_back from multithreads at the same time?

Tags: c++

I have multithreads program that each thread will return a string and then it will store in a shared vector container. I wonder is it possible for a std::vector to handle this case or I have to use locks to protect it?

Comment: You need a mutex or similar, vector is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Barring a handful of methods, only `const` methods are concurrency safe.

(those exceptions are iterator getting/index access methods)

If any thread does such non-`const` access, no other thread may do any access at all.